# Application of non-commutative geometry in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, phase-space, non-commutative-geometry

What are some of the applications of Connes' [non-commutative geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_geometry) in quantum mechanics?

Is it useful in defining and studying phase structure of a quantum system since we have $[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$ for a quantum system?